# Databases list not showing up?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

This morning when I logged into SQL Server Management Studio (v 10.0.16) I clicked on the databases node and saw all by db's (they are hosted remotely) as I have done for the last 3 years. This evening, when I click on the databases node I see NOTHING - except the system databases.

According to my hosting company, this is an issue with my local permissions. I have searched everywhere and found nothing to help me. I'm now desperate and and help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: This is very common with many hosting companies, they host many databases and there is limit on how many databases can be viewed in SSMS, if it crosses 2500 it will not show any databases, to fix this  Go to `View > Object Explorer Details`, then find your database and click on that to see objects under your database